# Batchfile to rename 5 folders (substitution)

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to:

- have 5 folders = 00, 11, 22, 33, 44   (00 acting as a dummy)
- and 4 batchfiles = BF11, BF22, BF33, BF44

I launch BF11 and have folder 11 become 00 and folder 00 become x11.

Suppose at this point I launch BF44 - this needs to:

- rename the current 00 back to its original (11) [by finding the existence of x11?]
- rename 44 into 00 and x11 into x44   [00 is now x44]

Now suppose I launch BF33, this needs to:

- rename the current 00 back to its original (44) [by finding the existence of x44?]
- rename 33 into 00 and x44 into x33    [00 is now x33]

And so on for each of the 4 combinations.

I hope it makes sense. Is this possible at all with batch files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
cd /d "whereveryouwant"
FOR %%i IN (00 11 22 33 44) DO IF .%1==.%%i GOTO swap
ECHO invalid parameter&pause&GOTO :eof
:swap
FOR %%i IN (11 22 33 44) DO IF EXIST x%%i (
 REN 00 %%i
 IF %1==00 REN x%%i 00&GOTO :EOF 
 REN %1 00
 REN x%%i x%1
 GOTO :eof
)
IF %1==00 GOTO :EOF 
REN 00 x%1
REN %1 00
GOTO :EOF
```

To make it easier, here's one batch file to do it. Simply run `thisbatch 11` (or `22`, etc.) after having edited `"whereveryouwant"` to be the name of the parent directory of 00, 11 etc.

The first thing it does is check that the parameter provided is valid and echo an error message and pause if it's invalid.

Then it looks for x11..x44. If it finds say `x33`, it

- changes `00` to `33`
- changes (say) `11` to `00`
- changes `x33` (the dummy) to `x11`
- exits

If it fails to find `x33`

- change `00` to (say) `x11`
- change `11` to `00`
- exit

The kink is for an entry of `00`. If `00` is supplied as a parameter, then it looks for x11..x44. If it finds say `x33`, it

- changes `00` to `33`
- changes `x33` (the dummy) to `00`
- exits

but if no 'x` directory is found, it does nothing.

Hence, entering '00' will restore the original directory set - `00` as the dummy.

I've used "`GOTO :EOF`" throughout - this is the normal method of exiting a batch. In your case, you'd probably need to change each of these to `EXIT` to shut the `CMD` window.

---

Revision to allow user-input

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
CD /d "c:\wherever\your\directories\are"
SET selection=%1
IF DEFINED selection GOTO validate
:getfromuser
SET "selection="
SET /p selection="Please enter selection 11..44 : "
IF NOT DEFINED selection GOTO :eof
:validate
FOR %%i IN (00 11 22 33 44) DO IF .%selection%==.%%i GOTO swap
ECHO invalid selection %selection%&GOTO getfromuser
:swap
FOR %%i IN (11 22 33 44) DO IF EXIST x%%i (
 REN 00 %%i
 IF %selection%==00 REN x%%i 00&GOTO :EOF 
 REN %selection% 00
 REN x%%i x%selection%
 GOTO :eof
)
IF %selection%==00 GOTO :EOF 
REN 00 x%selection%
REN %selection% 00
GOTO :EOF
```

Essentially the same program, except that if the selection isn't provided or an invalid selection is provided, the user will be prompted for a new selection. Responding with simply the enter key to this prompt will terminate the program.

If this is being run from a shortcut, it might be an idea to replace all the `GOTO :EOF` commands with `EXIT`

Comment: hi, Thank you both for your answers. i have tried Peter's code but i get an invalid parameter (to be sure i have a folder called k and inside it 00,11,22 etc..  so i changed "whereveryouwant" with "k")  ..i'm going to try the first example now

Comment: You'd probably need to use `C:\k` - the full path. When you run the batch, you need to run `thisbatch 11` (or 22, or 33 or 44 or 00) If you fail to give it a parameter, or give it a parameter other than one of those five, it will display `invalid Parameter`

Comment: well, i spent 3 hours with this trying what i think is everything and googling code, but could not make it work...  if anyone can lead me forward it would be great.. (also a remedy for headache please!)

Comment: Assuming you're setting up a shortcut for each of "switch to 11" to "switch to 44" then your shortcut's properties "Target" would be `C:\wherever\you\put\the\batch\whateveryouvecalledthebatch.bat` You would need to change this to `C:\wherever\you\put\the\batch\whateveryouvecalledthebatch.bat 11` to change to `11` and I'll leave you to your bottle of aspirin to figure out what to change for `22`, `33` and `44`. And `00` would reset you to the starting position - no `x` directory - just 00..44 as you started.

Comment: Peter, Thank you - it worked flawlessly.  had no idea i had to change the shortcut properties!   once that was clear, figuring out the rest, the bottle wasn't necessary...   yesterday i thought i had tiny insights into it...  way out of my league...  Thank You again for your generous help!

Answer (score 0):

The first part (renaming `00` appropriately) is straightforward: just use the appropriate `ren` command in each batch file.

You should be able to use this for the second part:

```
IF [NOT] EXIST filename command
```

e.g.

```
IF EXISTS x11 rename x11 xXX
IF EXISTS x22 rename x22 xXX
...
```

(where `xXX` depends on the batch file you're in, and you omit the line that would rename `xXX` to itself each time)

However, this all feels a little fragile and I wonder if there isn't a more robust solution to your underlying problem by using either a configuration management system or soft links.